# 7-Zip auto replace original file option

Tags: 7-zip

I right-clicked a folder and selected "Add to Archive..." from the "7-zip" drop down menu
[image]

then, a menu appears 
[image]
 from there I can archive the file, however, the program doesn't automatically delete the original. This there such an option for that? (7-zip, Windows 8.1)

Comment: Hmm. Are you running the latest version if 7zip? Mine (v15.14) has a checkbox "Delete files after compression" in the "Options" section: http://i.imgur.com/iXSrfBU.png

Comment: I used the search shortcut ,opened 7-zip manager, clicked help and then about. The menu that appeared 7-zip 9.20, so I guess I am not using the latest version?

Comment: I guess not ;) Try the latest version (http://www.7-zip.org/). If that works for you let me know I will write a full answer.

Comment: Great ;) Answer added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The program doesn't automatically delete the original.

> I used the search shortcut, opened 7-zip manager, clicked help and then about. The menu that appeared 7-zip 9.20, so I guess I am not using the latest version?

The latest version is 15.14.

It has a checkbox "Delete files after compression" in the "Options" section (which appears to be missing from version 9.20, according to the screenshot in the question).

This option (when checked) will remove the files after they are added to the archive.

[image]

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.